# How can I get data from multiple form fields, and then submit them with the same form into a single database cell as a array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

**This is part of my form in Rails:**

```
    # 2 fields that should have values passed into an array
    <%= f.label "test1" %>       
    <%= text_field_tag(:test1) %>
    <%= f.label "test2" %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:test2) %>

    # hidden field to (hopefully) receive the array data (same form)
    <%= f.hidden_field :subtypes, :value => @subtypes %>
```

**This is in my controller:**

```
  def update
    if @anomaly.update(anomaly_params)
     redirect_to anomaly_path(@anomaly)
     flash[:success] = "You have successfully updated the anomaly"
    else
     render :edit
     flash[:error] = @anomaly.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
```

**This method will run before the various methods:**  (before_action at the top of file)

```
# before_action :subtypes_array, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

def subtypes_array
  @subtypes = []
  field1 = params[:test1]
  field2 = params[:test2]
  @subtypes << field1
  @subtypes << field2
end
```

*I also have this in the controller:*

```
# before_action :set_anomaly, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def set_anomaly
  @anomaly = Anomaly.find(params[:id])
end
```

I have Rails 4 strong params to allow the data from the various fields through.
The form works without errors, but ***the data from the two fields never makes it into the database.***

I already have a database column that can receive an array with string values:

```
class AddSubtypesToAnomalies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :anomalies, :subtypes, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

From the console I can pass an array in no problem.

I am wondering how to make this work?

**UPDATE:**

```
private
  def anomaly_params
    params.require(:anomaly).permit(:test1, :test2, :name, :description, :subtypes)
  end
```

Comment: Can you please post the `def anomaly_params` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **text_field_tag**s need to be nested under the object

```
<%= text_field_tag("anomaly[test1]") %>
<%= text_field_tag("anomaly[test2]") %>
```

That's because the form_for you're using sets all the other fields under **anomaly**.  **anomaly_params** only grabs what's underneath **anomaly** in your **update** method.

#### UPDATE

Since you're using an Array in your DB field and you've chosen to use more than one field for the Array you need to capture it in both the create and update controller method.  With the same text_field_tags I've written here you would do:

```
def create
  
  create_subtypes
  
  if @anmaly.save(anomaly_params)
  ...

def update

  create_subtypes

  if @anomaly.update(anomaly_params)
  ...

private
def create_subtypes
  params['anomaly']['subtypes'] = Array(params['anomaly']['subtypes']) << params['anomaly'].delete('test1')
  params['anomaly']['subtypes'] = Array(params['anomaly']['subtypes']) << params['anomaly'].delete('test2')
end
```

To address the empty item at the beginning of the Array do as follows:

```
def create_subtypes
  params['anomaly']['subtypes'] = Array(params['anomaly']['subtypes'].presence).compact << params['anomaly'].delete('test1')
  params['anomaly']['subtypes'] = Array(params['anomaly']['subtypes'].presence).compact << params['anomaly'].delete('test2')
end
```

---

It might be easier to just create a regular :subtypes form field and let the user manually enter in their own comma separated list instead of using test1 and test2.

Comment: I get an 'unknown attribute: test1' error.  Only the subtypes exist in the database --the two test fields are just collecting the values.  Will this not work since the fields are under anomaly?  I must be missing something.

Comment: Can you place the scheme for the anomaly object here? Excerpt from /db/scheme ... I'm not quite sure what your db relationship table is like.

Comment: `create_table "anomalies", force: true do |t|`
    `t.string   "name"`
    `t.text     "description"`
    `t.datetime "created_at"`
    `t.datetime "updated_at"`
    `t.string   "subtypes",    default: [], array: true`
  `end`

Comment: I think you're right about just adding a comma separated list, I was trying to make it easier for a user to maintain a clear hierarchy in the list, but I could do that the other way too.   Your solution works now other than I am getting an empty value in the first slot in the array.  So instead of two entries there are three with the first one being an empty string.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Use both presence and compact for the Array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your controller that `subtypes` parameter is an array, otherwise it will not be handled as such, and since you have strong params, this is the way to do it:

```
private
  def anomaly_params
    params.require(:anomaly).permit(:test1, :test2, :name, :description, :subtypes=> [])
  end
```

Also use the full hash label for your parameters

```
field1 = params[:anomaly][:test1]
field2 = params[:anomaly][:test2]
```

Comment: I don't get errors this way and that makes sense, but I am still not getting the data into the database.

Comment: in the server log I can see that the two test fields are getting the values but they never make it to the subtypes array: `"subtypes"=>"[nil, nil]"`